# useEffect undefined on first rend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

What am i doing wrong here? I'm trying to fetch the data from my API but it keeps returning undefined on my first render, and the next render works fine.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3001/homeFeed")
        
        setData(res.data)
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])

  console.log(data)
// Output: 
// []
// []
// {users: Array(5), id_usuario_logado: 25}
// {users: Array(5), id_usuario_logado: 25}
// {users: Array(5), id_usuario_logado: 25}
// {users: Array(5), id_usuario_logado: 25}
```

Comment: *"but it keeps returning undefined"* - In the "output" example in code comments you claim it outputs an empty array, not `undefined`.  Which is it?

Comment: I changed it a bit, the returning was undefined but i defined the useState to be an Array, so now it's returning an empty Array in place of undefined

Comment: Then it sounds like it's outputting exactly what you initialize the value to.  This is expected behavior.  There's no actual problem here, you're just observing the fact that React re-renders a component when state changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how React works. React doesn't halt rendering until the request inside `useEffect` resolves.

Usually people either have a state like `isLoading` set to `true` at the start then `false` after the effect finishes, or use a library like tanstack-query (formerly react-query) which handles loading/error state (and more), and while its loading you can either have a loading spinner or display nothing.

Comment: Is there anything i can do to avoid this? What should be the correct aproach, because i can't use the map function if it returns undefined.

Comment: To avoid using methods on `undefined`, you can use the "optional chaining" operator `data?.map` or return `null` earlier in the method

Comment: The loading aproach worked, thanks, it was exactly what i needed.

Comment: Or just initialize it with an empty array as you changed it to in your post. Works just fine with map.

Comment: @Bqardi Their data acutally is an object with an array inside of it, so an empty array like in the post will still have errors on `data.users.map`

Comment: Right, my bad, still need optional chaining then or set state to users array.